# Ruby negated-if statements

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I have a statement checking if a string contains another; if it doesn't, it runs some code. I don't think I'm doing it in a very optimised way. Here is a code snippet:

```
if blocks_in_progress.include? ('|' + blocks[i])
else
    block = blocks[i]
    break
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit of a Ruby newbie here, but as far as I understand it, the following is the preferred way:

```
unless blocks_in_progress.include? ('|' + blocks[i])
   block = blocks[i]
   break
end
```

Source: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide (syntax section)

Answer (score 3):

A one liner:

```
 break block = blocks[i] unless blocks_in_progress.include? ('|' + blocks[i])
```